# How to import an .xlsx file into a SQL Server database on MacOS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, macos, azure-data-studio

I've set up an SQL server using Docker on MacOS computer. I've also installed SQL Operations Studio as a GUI.

In SQL Operations Studio I'm trying to import list "Data" from a multiple-sheet AllData.xlsx file into a newly created table "Data_test" in my database "TestDB" using this chunk of code:

```
USE TestDB;
GO
SELECT * INTO Data_test
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0; Database=/Users/user_name/Desktop/AllData.xlsx', [Data$]);
GO
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
"The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.ODBC.12.0" has not been registered."
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

A question like this has already been attempted to answer by this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bc04fec1-3563-4d4d-a06f-eb9ef89b0825/the-ole-db-provider-quotmicrosoftaceoledb120quot-has-not-been-registered-running-sql?forum=sqldataaccess). It is advised to use ODBC instead of OLEDB, but the [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ODBC-drivers-that-are-compatible-with-Excel-for-Mac-9FA6BC7F-D19E-4F7F-9BE4-92E85C77D712) given in the answer refers to importing into Excel from a database, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Overall, I'm looking for some way to import .xlsx files into a SQL server databases on Mac without using Windows. I would switch from SQL Operation Studio if it solves the issue.

Comment: It's doubtful. OLE DB depends on automation, which is based on ActiveX, which is a Windows only technology.

Comment: [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bc04fec1-3563-4d4d-a06f-eb9ef89b0825/the-ole-db-provider-quotmicrosoftaceoledb120quot-has-not-been-registered-running-sql?forum=sqldataaccess) it is advised to use ODBC instead of OLEDB. Can it possibly help?

Comment: Yes, ODBC is cross-platform, so you can probably find a driver for Access.

Comment: Can you use TXT/CSV?

Comment: I could, if helps to solve the problem